# How to connect SFTP in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, magento-connect, file

I want to connect the SFTP in Magento  2

here is my code.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$sftp = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
$open =  $sftp->open(array('host' => 'hostname','username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',));

 if ($open)
 {
 echo "true";
 }  
 else
 {
 echo "false";
 }
```

but does not work that code.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code, but it works fine, except for the if statement. That if statement always returns false, even if the connection is open. So i've added a var_dump at the end. It lists all existing files in the root of the SFTP server. With that var_dump you can verify the SFTP connection.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$sftp = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
$open =  $sftp->open(
    array(
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
    )
);

var_dump($sftp->ls());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes,my code is workin fine, I think i used wrong password of the sftp and thank for comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code with some modification and I am able to connect in your code port no. is missing.

```
  <?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$sftp = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
$open =  $sftp->open(
                    array(
                        'host' => 'myhostname',
                        'username' => 'myusername',
                        'password' => 'mypassword',
                        'port' =>22,
                        'passive' => true
                    )
                );
        if(is_null($connection)){
        echo "true";
        //Here is code ....
        }else{
            echo "false";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly install PHP ssh2 extension and then use the following code.**

```
$strServer = '*******';
$strServerPort = '*******';
$strServerUsername = '*******';
$strServerPassword = '*******';

//connect to server
$resConnection = ssh2_connect($strServer, $strServerPort);

if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword))
{
     //Initialize SFTP subsystem            
     echo "connected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $connection = new \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp();
        $connection->open(
            ['host' => $host, 'username' => $login, 'password' => $password]
        );

        $connection->cd($dirPath);
        $pwd = $connection->pwd();
        $connection->write($pwd .'/'. $ftpFileName, $filePath);
        $connection->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code from my project.

```
$sftp = $obj->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
  $open =  $sftp->open(
       array(
           'host' => $sftp_hostname,
           'username' => $sftp_username,
           'password' => $sftp_password,
           'port'=>$sftp_port
       )
    );

    try{
        // Change directory and move to require directory
        $sftp->cd('/enter_your_sftp_file_path_here/');

        //Fetching/Listing all the files.
        $sftp_server_files = $sftp->ls();

        //File path to put files from SFTP Server to our local server
        $filepath = $dir->getRoot() . '/var/import/inventory/';

        foreach ($sftp_server_files as $file) {

            //Copy files from server
            $source = $file['text'];
            if(strpos($source, 'zip') !== false){
                $destination = $filepath.$source;
                $result = $sftp->read($source, $destination);
                if($result == 'true') {
                   $message[] = 'File read from SFTP server : '.$source;
                }
                else
                {
                  $message[] = 'File not able to read from SFTP server : '.$source;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```