# Magento2.3: How to connect SFTP?

Tags: magento2.3, server-setup, ftp

**I want to connect SFTP in magento 2 but not sure where to start.**

I have seen some of the post regarding this but not understand where to put the code.

> Below is one of the link which I have referred.

[How to connect SFTP in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263630/how-to-connect-sftp-in-magento-2)

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.hexascholars.com/code-snippet/connect-different-servers-using-sftp-in-magento2/

Comment: Please try - https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/45784266/

Comment: @AnasMansuri, Thanks, I will check and let you know.

Comment: @ShafeelSha, Thanks, Will check and let you know

Comment: Checked and see that those links has only code and not mentioned that where to put it.