# Magento2.3: How to send a file using SFTP connection?

Tags: magento2.3, server-setup, ftp

I have successfully connected SFTP in magento 2 by referring the below URL:

[How to connect SFTP in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263630/how-to-connect-sftp-in-magento-2)

Now, I want to send a file to that server. In order to send a file, how can I proceed?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $serverInfo = [
                'host' => "host",
                'username' => "username",
                'password' => "pwd",
            ];   
// use construct injection sftp : \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp
$this->sftp->open($serverInfo); //the serverinfo is server config
$this->sftp->cd($path);//the path is you will upload path
$this->sftp->write($filename, $source); // filename and string data or local file name
$this->sftp->close();
```

Comment: Thanks. What I have to put to $path. Also Could you please explain a little bit about this code because I'm new to this SFTP?

Comment: The path of the ftp machine you want to upload.